# Vuetify3: Resizing Browser Window Width Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a .vue file that creates a basic search page using VUETIFY, when serving the application with `npm run serve`, the code runs fine, and the webpage and all methods work, with no errors, it is only if you open inspect element and resize the width until it is at its smallest that you get the error. I thought this might be a deeper bug in the library itself.

Error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth')
    at calculateUpdatedOffset (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSlideGroup/helpers.mjs:21:53)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSlideGroup/VSlideGroup.mjs:133:105)
```

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Here is the template code for the file (Since none of the javascript actually deals with any css attributes, I have assumed the javascript would be redundant):

```
<template>
  <v-container class="mb-16">
    <p class="text-h4">Search</p>
    <v-sheet max-width="500" class="mx-auto">
    <v-form v-model="valid">
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="6"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="searchTerms"
              label="search authors and books"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>

          <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="6"
          >
            <v-btn block class="mt-2" @click="requestData()">Submit</v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
    </v-sheet>
    <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="this.pages.length"></v-pagination>
    <v-alert
        v-if="this.alert"
        :type="this.alertType"
        title="Alert"
        :text="this.alertMessage"
    ></v-alert>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" v-for="(book, index) in this.pages[this.page - 1]" :key="index">
        <BookComponent 
          :title="book.volumeInfo.title" 
          :author="getValue(book.volumeInfo, 'authors[0]')" 
          :cover="getValue(book.volumeInfo, 'imageLinks.thumbnail')" 
          :pageCount="getValue(book.volumeInfo, 'pageCount')" 
          :searching="true"
          :keyId="index"
        />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

I thought the problem would have been with the `max-width` att in the `<v-sheet>` tag but removing this produces the same error.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: You have a call to `[this.page - 1]`, a negative index. It'll get passed `-1` right off the bat, so I'm not surprised you get a null pointer exception because it is unlikely you have a -1 index populated...

Comment: @Nelson (Since none of the javascript actually deals with any css attributes, I have assumed the javascript would be redundant). clientWidth is never mentioned in the javascript, the javascript would be redundant for this question.

Comment: @Nelson, the code works fine until you resize the page down to its smallest bit, I also dealt with the issue you mentioned a long time ago, it never returns a negative index as the value is already set in the javascript, as I said before, the javascript isn't the issue, it has to do with resizing the page.